# Labels Causing Text Boxes to Deselect

Tags: html, forms

I am learning how to make forms and made this for practice.  When I have labels out it and try to click into any of the form elements, it selects the previous one.  For example, if I click into the password input box, it sends me to the username input box.  When I remove the labels the bug goes away.  I'm pretty sure labels aren't supposed to do this.  The console isn't showing any errors so I'm confused to why this is acting up.

Here is my code:

```
        <form action="">
            <fieldset>
                <label>username<label>
                <input type="text" id="userInput"/>
                <label>password<label>
                <input type="password" id="passwordInput"/>
                <label>Hidden<label>
                <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" value="I can't tell you"/>
                <label>Text Area<label>
                <textArea id="areaInput" rows="10" cols="40">
                This is a big area with lots of text.
                </textArea>
                <input type="button" onClick="" value="submit"/>
            <fieldset>
        <form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are not closing your label tags, so you are making another label.  You need to close the `<label>` by using `</label>` - just a typo!

Comment: Thanks I should have checked more carefully

Comment: Easy typing mistake to make! :)

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing out your `<label>` tag. Use the `/` slash on the closing tag:

```
<label>username</label>
```